# Can't get regex patterns right

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I made a function that replaces multiple instances of a single character with multiple patterns depending on the character location.

There were two ways I found to accomplish this:

1. This one looks horrible but it works:

def xSubstitution(target_string):

```
while target_string.casefold().find('x') != -1:

    x_finded = target_string.casefold().find('x')

    if (x_finded == 0 and target_string[1] == ' ') or (target_string[x_finded-1] == ' ' and 
       ((target_string[-1] == 'x' or 'X') or target_string[x_finded+1] == ' ')):

        target_string = target_string.replace(target_string[x_finded], 'ecks', 1)

    elif (target_string[x_finded+1] != ' '):

        target_string = target_string.replace(target_string[x_finded], 'z', 1)
    else:

        target_string = target_string.replace(target_string[x_finded], 'cks', 1)

return(target_string)
```

2. This one technically works, but I just can't get the regex patterns right:

   import re

def multipleRegexSubstitutions(sentence):

```
patterns = {(r'^[xX]\s'): 'ecks ', (r'[^\w]\s?[xX](?!\w)'): 'ecks',
            (r'[\w][xX]'): 'cks', (r'[\w][xX][\w]'): 'cks',
            (r'^[xX][\w]'): 'z',(r'\s[xX][\w]'): 'z'}

regexes = [
    re.compile(p)
    for p in patterns
]

for regex in regexes:
    for match in re.finditer(regex, sentence):
        match_location = sentence.casefold().find('x', match.start(), match.end())
        sentence = sentence.replace(sentence[match_location], patterns.get(regex.pattern), 1)
return sentence
```

From what I figured it out, the only problem in the second function is the regex patterns. Could someone help me?

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to tell that the regexes are looking for the different x characters in a string, and replace an X in the beggining of a word for a 'Z', in the middle or end of a word for 'cks' and if it is a lone 'x' char replace with 'ecks'

Comment: What is the string that you're trying to apply this to? Can you give an example?

Comment: Hi, I tried a somewhat random string just to test various ways X could appear.

sentence = "X is exact xylophone X x Xyhukl jXsa xa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `\b` (word boundary) and `\B` (position other than word boundary):

> Replace an X in the beggining of a word for a 'Z'

```py
re.sub(r'\bX\B', 'Z', s, flags=re.I)
```

> In the middle or end of a word for 'cks'

```py
re.sub(r'\BX', 'cks', s, flags=re.I)
```

> If it is a lone 'x' char replace with 'ecks'

```py
re.sub(r'\bX\b', 'ecks', s, flags=re.I)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the following set of substitutions for this:

```
string = re.sub(r"\b[Xx]\b", "ecks", string)
string = re.sub(r"\b[Xx](?!\s)", "Z", string)
string = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)[Xx](?=\w)", "cks", string)
```

Here,

```
(?!\s)
```

just asserts that the regex does not match any whitespace character,

```
\b
```

**Edit**: The last regex would also match `x` or `X` at the beginning of a word. So we can use the following, instead,

```
(?<=\w)[xX](?=\w)
```

to make sure there *must* be a character `\w` before/after `x` or `X`.